# show one result per person sorted by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

in my local website, people can pass a test, and administrator can see the result.
before, all the result were display but it was ugly, so I decided to show only the last test people pass. but I'm stuck because I can show only one result per person, but I can't sort him by date :(

```
SELECT * FROM resultateval join personne using (id) group by id
```

this is the query who show one result per people and here is the table.

[image]

it's supposed to show

```
654321 / 08-06-2018 / 12 : 02 / 5 / 8 / 1
 A256589 / 05-06-2018 /13 : 05 / 7 / 10 / 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Please add a tag for the database product you are using postgresql, oracle, sql-server, db2

Comment: i'm on mysql with phpmyadmin, that's all i know :/

Comment: MySQL was the magic word we were looking for :-)

Comment: Do you expect a _single_ record for each `id`, or do you want a _single_ record for each `id`, for each date?

Comment: a single record for each id :) and it's type date for dateeval

Comment: What is the type of the `dateeval` column?  Is it text, or is it an actual date?

Comment: As to the datamodel: Why are date and time separated columns? Is this about whole day and weekly occurences where date or time must be nullable? Usually this should be one datetime column. Then: A column called `id` should uniquely identify a record in a table (hence the name). Joining two different tables on `id` would make no sense (if they are not 1:1 related, which is an extremely rare case, and even then they should better not both be called `id`). You may want to remane these columns.

Comment: With two tables involved, you should tell us which columns belong to which table. And how do you find "the last test people pass" in your tables? Is every record a passed test? Or must we check one of the columns to tell passed from failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you stored time and date separately, the query you'll need to do this is relatively ugly.  We can form an effective timestamp by using `ADDTIME` to add the `heuereeval` time to the `dateeval` date.  Then, this is just a basic aggregation join query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM resultateval t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MAX(ADDTIME(dateeval, heureeval)) AS max_date
    FROM resultateval
    GROUP BY id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       ADDTIME(t1.dateeval, t1.heureeval) = t2.max_date;
```

[image]

### Demo

For future reference, avoid storing the date and time separately, unless there is a very good reason for doing so (and I don't see one here).

**Edit:** As a I feared, based on comments it appears that you have stored your dates as text.  You can use the following function call to generate a date based on the date's text:

```
STR_TO_DATE(dateeval, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Just replace in my original query `dateeval` with the above call to `STR_TO_DATE` and it should still work.

Comment: it seem to work with you, it don't work with me bcz i'm stupid and i put date into varchar......i gonna change his type and use your query, thank you so much for your time !
PS : yeah i use time and date because people can pass the exam as many time he want, so the administrator can see if the people pass the test 5 time in 10 minute instead of 5 time in one day for example

Comment: @PaulTanné You may use `STR_TO_DATE` as a workaround here, to parse your text dates into real dates.

Comment: got it, i'm better with javascript :'( :p

Comment: Don't say that ! you're the best !

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is very wrong. You group by `id`, but you select all columns. As `id` is not unique in your joined data, this makes no sense and is invalid SQL. You cannot say: "Give me **the** `dateeval` (etc.) for the `id`". You must say something like: " "Give me **the minimum / maximum / average** `dateeval` for the `id`".

This query should result in an error, but MySQL outside `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode let's this slip and silently converts `select *` to `select id, any_value(dateeval), any_value(heureeval) ...`. So you get arbitrarily picked values that can even stem from different records.

What you want is something like this:

```
select *
from resultateval 
join personne using (id)
where (id, timestamp(dateeval,heureeval)) in
(
  select id, max(timestamp(dateeval,heureeval)) 
  from resultateval 
  join personne using (id)
  group by id
);
```